# How to hide file path in VSCode terminal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can someone please help me with this one? Is there a way to hide this path in VSCode terminal? I only want to display the output without that path. [Path in VSCode. Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5BmW.png)

Comment: your next question would then be: `Sometimes my program does not run.` Now it will always run

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this is solved by the shell itself in the system. You can customize the terminal as described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/16728/hide-current-working-directory-in-terminal or https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes